# item-center not working in tailwindcss with NextJS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using NextJS with tailwindcss. I did the setup according to the official documentation https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/styling-tips. (See section for tailwind)

For some commands such as bg for background color or width tailwindcss is working, but somehow some other tailwindcss commands like "items-center" are not working properly.

```
        <div className="w-screen bg-[#444] items-center">
          <div className="max-w-[200px] bg-[#AAA]">
```

In this example the string inside className, contains the tailwindcss commands. "w-screen" and bg-[#444] is working properly, (I tried different colors and width commands, to be sure, they are all working") Somehow the "items-center" is not working. It should center the items of the div element, but they all stick to the left side.

I re-checked the setup multiple times with the documentation, but probably I sill missed something, so here are the neccessary linces i have in the config files, etc.

tailwind.congig.js:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
      './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
      './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    plugins: [],
  }
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

globals.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

_app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items` property determines the default alignment for items within a flexbox or grid container.

It's not an issue with Tailwind-CSS. It's the way you apply the `align-items` without the `grid` or `flex` container.

Documentaions of [align-items](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.php).

---

The following should do the trick:

```html
<div className="flex w-screen bg-[#444] items-center">
    <div className="max-w-[200px] bg-[#AAA]">
```

```html
<div className="grid w-screen bg-[#444] items-center">
    <div className="max-w-[200px] bg-[#AAA]">
```